# Is there a way of returning back the question and answer from the database not done correctly in a test by the user?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a short php quiz quizzer. For the question not done correctly, i want the code to be able  return the question number and supposed answer and for the correct question i want to increase the score

So far the coding is working but when i tried to add the number of the incorrect question and its correct answer to an array $wrong_answer i got stack and can't figure out the way around

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 

      //Check to see if score is set_error_handler
    if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
       $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    }


//Check if form was submitted
if($_POST){

    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $next=$number+1;
    $wrong_answer = array();
    $lesson = (int) $_GET['l']; 

    //Get total number of questions
    $query = "select * from questions where lesson_number = $lesson";
    $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    $total=$results->num_rows;

    //Get correct choice
    $q = "select * from `choices` where question_number = $number and is_correct=1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($q) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $correct_choice=$row['id'];



    //compare answer with result
    if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }else {
        foreach($number and $correct_choice){
            $wrong_answer [] = $number, $correct_choice;
        }
    }

    if($number == $total){
        header("Location: final.php");
        exit();
    } else {
            header("Location: B.php?n=".$next."&l=$lesson&score=".$_SESSION['score']);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: imagine some evil person posting `0; DROP TABLE choices; --`as number. then read about parameterised queries. then use them to secure your database.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja i am getting this; page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i will do so, thanks

Comment: I guess there might be database access issue or your php file path might be invalid try to debug by removing sql queries if it runs fine and Are you sure only that invalid_answer array is causing 500 error

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja am sure, it was after i added this code   
 `if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
  $_SESSION['score']++;
 }else {
  foreach($number and $correct_choice){
   $wrong_answer [] = $number $correct_choice;
  }
 }`

Comment: remove the else part check if it works just to debug m saying

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja it is working is working when i remove the else part

Answer (score 0):

why are you writing a foreach loop when the variable isn't an array?
did you mean to do

```
if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
    $_SESSION['score']++;
}else {
     $wrong_answer=[$number,$correct_choice];
}
```

or

```
if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
    $_SESSION['score']++;
}else {
     array_push($wrong_answer,[$number, $correct_choice]);//for 2d array
}
```

Comment: i want to run the code until the total number of question is reached, `$query = "select * from questions where lesson_number = $lesson";
 $results = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
 $total=$results->num_rows;`  then save then question's id number's as `$number` and their correct choice's id numbers as `$correct_choice`, then i will later have another page where i will return the question's done wrong and their correct answers when the test is complete